# Unexpected Timer/Counter B interrupt frequency on ATtiny204

Tags: c, avr-gcc, atmelstudio, attiny

I'm trying to implement a timing system on an ATtiny204 using Timer/Counter B in Microchip studio but I'm getting a very unexpected interrupt frequency based on my register and fuse settings.

I have my `OSCCFG.FREQSEL` fuse set to the 20MHz clock, and I'm initializing the clock controller with the following two lines which should give me a 20Mhz `CLK_CPU` and a 312.5kHz `CLK_PER`

```
CLKCTRL.MCLKCTRLA = CLKCTRL_CLKSEL_OSC20M_gc; //Select internal 20Mhz oscillator
CLKCTRL.MCLKCTRLB = CLKCTRL_PDIV_64X_gc | CLKCTRL_PEN_bm; //Set peripheral clock to 1/64th of CPU clock
```

I'm initializing the Timer/Counter B module with the following lines:

```
TCB0.CCMP = MATCH_VALUE; //Some value such that we get 1000 interrupts per second
TCB0.CTRLB = TCB_CNTMODE_INT_gc; //Periodic interrupt mode
TCB0.EVCTRL = TCB_CAPTEI_bm; //Enable input capture event (probably not needed)
TCB0.CTRLA = TCB_CLKSEL_CLKDIV1_gc | TCB_ENABLE_bm; //Use CLK_PER not CLK_PER/2 and enable timer
TCB0.INTCTRL = TCB_CAPT_bm; //Enable interrupt
```

From what I read in the datasheet, in periodic interrupt mode, the timer counts until there's a match between its value and `TCB0.CCMP` then triggers the interrupt, and starts counting again from zero. The interrupt handler just increments a master timestamp `uint16_t` and flips a pin on and off so I can read the interrupt frequency with a logic analyzer, and clears the interrupt flag.

```
ISR(TCB0_INT_vect){
    if(++master & 1)
        VPORTA.OUT &= ~_BV(4);
    else
        VPORTA.OUT |= _BV(4);
    TCB0_INTFLAGS = TCB_CAPT_bm; //Clear the flag that triggered this interrupt
}
```

From my understanding, the proper value for `MATCH_VALUE` should be 20000000/64/1000 which is about 312, but this value gives me an interrupt frequency of about 10.6kHz.

I've found from experimentation that 3360 (0xD20) gives me almost exactly a 1kHz signal, but I cannot figure out how that makes sense mathematically based on the settings.

I originally thought my microcontroller was damaged and the clock was just going at the wrong speed, but I tried the firmware on a new chip and got the same behavior.

What is wrong in my code or my math? Is it safe to use my value from experimentation or have I done something that will cause other issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some special function registers (SFRs) on Xmega devices have a configuration change protection (CCP).  Before writing to such an SFR, one has to write a special pass-byte to the `CCP` register, think "password".

Also this is a timed sequence which means that the write to the target SFR has to be carried out within a few CPU cycles after writing the correct byte to `CCP`.  This means

- C/C++ is unsafe because you have no control over the instructions the compiler generates and over its timings.

In addition, interrupts have to be disabled. As far as I remember, writing the right pass-byte to `CCP` *starts an atomic sequence* for some cycles, but better check against the data sheet.  In that case, no explicit disabling IRQs is required even when IRQs might be on.

AVR-LibC provides an inline assembly macro to facilitate such writes:

```cpp
#include <avr/io.h>
// In some function:
    // Select internal 20 MHz oscillator.
    _PROTECTED_WRITE (CLKCTRL.MCLKCTRLA, CLKCTRL_CLKSEL_OSC20M_gc);
    // Set peripheral clock to 1/64th of CPU clock.
    _PROTECTED_WRITE (CLKCTRL.MCLKCTRLB, CLKCTRL_PDIV_64X_gc | CLKCTRL_PEN_bm);
```

---

In addition, there is `ccp_write_io()` in `avr/cpufunc.h` which calls a library function (and thus would generate more overhead in general).  Also mind [AVR-LibC issue #906](https://github.com/avrdudes/avr-libc/issues/906).

Answer (score 1):

I missed a section of the datasheet that said that `CLKCTRL.MCLKCTRLA` and `CLKCTRL.MCLKCTRLB` were write-protected, so writing to those registers was being silently ignored by the CPU and the default `CLK_CPU` -> `CLK_PER` prescaler value of 6 was being used instead of the expected value of 64, which I based my math on.

```
CPU_CCP = 0xD8; //Unprotect CLKCTRL.MCLKCTRLA
CLKCTRL.MCLKCTRLA = CLKCTRL_CLKSEL_OSC20M_gc; //Select internal 20Mhz oscillator
CPU_CCP = 0xD8; //Unprotect CLKCTRL.MCLKCTRLB
CLKCTRL.MCLKCTRLB = CLKCTRL_PDIV_64X_gc | CLKCTRL_PEN_bm; //Set peripheral clock to 1/64th of CPU clock
```

After the insertion of those two lines the frequency became what I was expecting.